# Deploy a spring boot war to websphere 7.5

Tags: spring

I have a Spring boot war(ReESTful webservice with Spring) built using a gradle build. Initially I built an executable jar and then converted into war. But I am not able to deploy this on websphere 7.5 app server. It can be deployed on Websphere 8.0. I read that spring boot war built without having web.xml is only supported in WAS 8 or above. How can i convert this to a war file that can be deployed on WAS 7.5?

I read that I need to add a web.xml to the war, but what what should be the content of the web.xml so that it can load all the controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot doesn't support Servlet 2.5 officially, but it doesn't take a lot to make it work. You might find this useful: https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-legacy.

You can get more information at the [official documantation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-servlet-2-5).